# How open an AES encrypted .zip?

Tags: php, aes

Can anybody please let me know, How open an AES encrypted .zip?. I need an encryption method should be `128-bit or 256-bit AES`. As well as this should be a PHP process.

any references...appreciable.

Comment: You would have to match however it was encrypted...

Comment: Can you please add your solution with this question?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I found an class that might help http://www.phpaes.com/ there's a free and a paid version, though, but it might get you on your way. After decripting youd have to do the decompresion with any of these http://www.php.net/manual/en/refs.compression.php

I hope this was useful.

Good luck!

***Edit***

Found a free one: http://www.phpclasses.org/package/4238-PHP-Encrypt-and-decrypt-data-with-AES-in-pure-PHP.html

Comment: also note that phpaes is **extremely** slow

Comment: @Longpoke indeed, perhaps the best choice is shell commands, but im not sure Prabhu can call those

Comment: AFAIK Mcrypt uses native code so it should be fast: http://php.net/manual/en/book.mcrypt.php